What's the difference between [abp] and [abp-framework]?
I just stumbled upon abp (currently over 800 questions) and abp-framework (currently 13 questions).

What's the difference?
Should questions with abp-framework be retagged with abp?


Frankly, I'd think the [tag:abp-framework] tag is more a descriptive tag name and should be the primary in any merged tag.

Thus synonimize [tag:abp] with [tag:abp-framwork] with latter as primary and swap (if necessary) the tag description.

@Paulie_D I doubt anyone has enough rep in the tag to do just that

You don't need (anyone to have) rep in the tag. Any mod can single-handedly do it

Is [tag:abp.io] the same thing as well or different?

@HenryEcker The tag wiki for [tag:abp] includes an abp.io link, so yes
